# Require Custom Taxonomy for Custom Type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have created a fairly unexciting custom type (Event) and an equally vanilla custom taxonomy (Venue).  Whenever a user creates an Event, I want them to be required to either create a new Venue or select an existing Venue.  How can I make this a required field when publishing?

It seems like the sort of thing that should be rather trivial but I've been going up and down http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy and haven't found anything obvious.  Am I going about this in the wrong way?

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hook an 'init' action callback in which you get the post-type and if it's 
'event' check $_POST for if your taxonomy value is empty. If it's empty, you can then reset $_POST['action'] to 'edit', so that post.php simply reloads the editor. And you can inject $_GET['message'] = 11 and add your (11th) response message via hooking a callback to the 'post_updated_messages' filter. That's not ideal, but it's somewhat of a solution.

Comment: I've been looking around for the last week and this really appears to be the only solution.  Maybe a useful direction for a new plugin.

Comment: @Robert Drake: I think this should be somehow addressed in core. It's kinda similar to another wish i have...which is ability to specify taxonomies as unique, by which i mean you can only select one value per post. There's a certain level of input logic that one can't define easily in WP, so far.